# can't connect to copied Amazon ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I have a linux instance that I set up a while ago to host a ruby website.  I can connect to it via ssh, ping it and browse the website.  I wanted to make a copy of this instance and upgrade the copy, so I created an AMI off of the instance, then launched an instance off of the AMI.

I can ssh into the new instance perfectly.  however, I cannot ping it or browse the website.  It is using the same security group as the original instance which has inbound rules for all IMCP and TCP traffic from my IP.  The availability zone changed from us-east-1c to us-east-1a

I am at a loss as to why the copies instance isn't working.  Does anyone have any ideas why I can't ping or browse the new instance in a web browser?

Thanks!

Comment: Perform a packet capture on the server to see if your traffic is getting there. If not, you know where to start looking...

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options you have:

**Startup logs:** There is a possibility to check the systems status by looking into the startup logs. If some process crashes during startup, it can cause the system to become unreachable.

**Elastic IP:** Did you give the instance an external IP?

**VPC:** If your instance is in another zone, it can be that the subnet of that zone does not have a route to the gateway.

Please write when this is not helping you out.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if there's a local firewall running on the host that would block such things as ICMP and other traffic. Is UFW, IPTables or something else contributing to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.  They were actually different security groups.  I got a little confused because it was using the same value for the 'Key Name' field, which I thought was tied to security group and the security group column was mostly off the end of my screen and I didn't notice the difference.  So I just opened up ports in the new security group and everything worked perfectly.  Thanks for the suggestions!  I'm sure they'll come in handy in the future.